# Javascript Object returns empty when called

Tags: javascript, node.js, faunadb

a piece of my code

```
const channels = fauna.paginate(q.Match(q.Index("channels"), "true")) // Query FaunaDB database for channel list => create constant called users containing results
const channelList = channels.each(function (page) {
  // Logs the page's contents,
  // for example: [ Ref(Collection("test"), "1234"), ... ]
  console.log(page);
});
```

works fine and behaves how it supposed to. however, when I try to call "channelList" from elsewhere in my code it returns {}
The console.log in the first piece of code returns what it is supposed to as well so I dont think there is anything wrong with the first chunk of code.

Here is a piece of code where I attempt to call this object

```
  let options = {
    options: {
      debug: config.twitchConfig.options.debug
    },
    connection: {
      reconnect: config.twitchConfig.options.reconnect,
      secure: config.twitchConfig.options.secure
    },
    identity: {
      username: config.twitchConfig.connection.username,
      password: config.twitchConfig.connection.password
    },
    channels: [JSON.stringify(channelList)] // Attempt to call here, Returns {} (Empty object)
  };
```

Is there something I'm missing? is this even possible in the first place? if its not possible whats another method i can use to achieve the same result?

Edit: From what I can gather, channelList is based off of the page response, and it seems like the page response is private to that function and cannot be referenced outside of the function. what can I do to either make it referencable outside of the function or create a constant/variable that can be accessed outside of the function containing the same information

Comment: `.each`? Did you mean `forEach`? If so, please note that it returns undefined. Or is `each` a library method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox when using forEach it just returns "channels.forEach is not a function" thats why its not used there. the way it is in the first snippet seems to work fine so im guessing its a part of the faunadb library

Comment: Well a console log returns undefined so maybe try putting something which returns inside the `each` method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry i'm pretty dumb most of the time. what do you mean by something which returns? also, the console.log(page); that is in that first snippet returns 
[ '#sniperbotontwitch' ]
Which is what it should return, but when calling that same constant outside of the channels.each function it returns {} or [object object]
Also, i've updated the post containing my evaluation of what the issue could be

Comment: What is the type of `channels`? What does `channels[Symbol.iterator]` return?

Comment: @BenAston I'm really sorry but i'm finding it very hard to understand what you're trying to say. I havent heard of the terms you're referring to. Would you be able to explain it to me like i'm 2? thank you

Comment: Do you want `channelList` to be an array of objects? And what does `console.log(channels[Symbol.iterator])` print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error my answer was way simpler than me or anyone else I have spoken to thought.

Here's a step by step guide on how to fix the problem yourself if you're experiencing the same issue as I was.

1. Use a variable instead of a constant
2. declare your variable before setting it by placing `var channelList;` somewhere above your code that sets it
3. set the previously declared variable with a simple `channelList = page`
4. `console.log(channelList);` just to make sure its all working
5. Finally, call the variable where you want it, and voila! you have your variable properly called and it doesn't return {} or Undefined or [Object Object]

Answer (score 0):

channelList is not a function, more like it is the result of a function that prints the channels.. so after printing what is assigned to it is the result..
Try assuming it as a function and then invoking it:

```
const channelList = ()=>{
 channels.each(function (page) {
  // Logs the page's contents,
  // for example: [ Ref(Collection("test"), "1234"), ... ]
  console.log(page);
});
};

channelList();
```

Assuming the code itself does what you want it to, this should do the job

Comment: This brings me closer to an answer, thanks for that!
However, now when that constant is called further down the line it's contents is
()=>{ channels.each(function (page) {
  // Logs the page's contents,
  // for example: [ Ref(Collection("test"), "1234"), ... ]
  console.log(page);
});
}
instead of a simple 
[ 'DATA' ]

Comment: What do you want to happen the second time? You are creating a string of the function.. if you want to print the values of channels, call the function outside options.. and give channels the channels const

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying to print the values of Page. Your answer definitely got me closer to the answer im looking for. thanks for that, i'll just keep playing with different things and hopefully I can get what i want <3